# Can feature importance be used to explain the "why and which feature contributed" to model predictions?

Tags: classification, prediction, xgboost, feature-selection, non-linear

I have a XGBoost(classificaion) model with ~75% accuracy using N-variables and the feature importance list of the model. My question is - for a given row and a prediction score - can I explain which features led to a 1 or a 0 prediction ?

Answer (score 0):

I have used [xgboostExplainer](https://github.com/AppliedDataSciencePartners/xgboostExplainer) for this purpose. This R package creates a plot for each sample showing the score and cumulative contribution of each variable to the final prediction, e.g.

This sample was predicted to be positive:

[image: sample_1.png]

This sample was predicted to be negative:

[image: sample_2.png]

The height of the bars is dependant on the importance of the variable AND the score for that variable for that sample, i.e. for a given sample you can see which variables contributed to the final prediction and why.

Comment: Thankyou, this is exactly what I was looking for, is there any similar package in python which gives a similar output?

Comment: Not to my knowledge. If you require a python-specific solution please tag python in your question.